# Socle of representations of Klein Four group over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: finite-groups, modules, representation-theory, socle

I am trying to answer Q7. from page 11 of http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/RepBook/RepBookLatex.pdf

The question states:

"Let $G= \langle x, y \ \mid \ x^2=y^2=1 \rangle$  be the Klein four-group, $R=\mathbb{F}_2$  and consider the two representations $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ specified on the generators of $G$ by

$$ \rho_1(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \rho_1(y) = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$ \rho_2(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \rho_2(y) = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Calculate the socles of these two representations. Show that neither representation is
semisimple."

The text previous gives the following as the definition of the socle "The largest semisimple submodule of a module $U$ ($A$ is a ring with a $1$, $U$ is an $A$-module of finite composition length) is called the socle of $U$, and is
denoted $\operatorname{Soc}(U)$." The text also notes "The sum of all simple submodules of a module is the unique largest semisimple
submodule of that module: the socle."

I am having a hard time making sense of this definition and applying it. I am not sure what the submodules are in this case or how to tell what the submodules are in general when given explicit representations.

This is one of the first examples I am considering in this topic so any extra detail you could give me would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Are you considering row vectors or column vectors?

Comment: column vectors, so would the 3 x 1 columns be the submodules?

Comment: Then in rep 2, I see $\pmatrix{*\\*\\0}$ as a two dimensional semisimple submodule, but I don't see anything similar in rep 1.

Comment: I think I'm missing something fundamental as I'm not sure what makes the vector you have given two dimensional and semisimple. Using the definition I have a semisimple submodule is a direct sum of simple modules, given the vector you have stated what would the direct summands be? (thank you for your help)